# Guardar un documento excel (con pandas python) en una variable

Tags: python, excel, pandas, aws

Estoy haciendo un programa donde abro un documento `excel` desde **S3 (AWS)**, lo filtro y después lo guardo (se guarda en mi equipo) y ese mismo archivo filtrado lo subo a **S3**, ahí todo bien pero ese mismo programa lo subo a **lambdas** **(AWS)** y me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y creo es porque el programa busca guardar el archivo filtrado localmente y en **lambda** no lo puede hacer, entonces necesito que ese archivo que ya filtre se mantenga en alguna variable para después poderlo subir a **S3**.
Gracias.

Código:

```
#Importamos las bibliotecas pandas & tinys3
import pandas as pd
import tinys3

# Conexion a S3
conn = tinys3.Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY,S3_SECRET_KEY)

# Declaramos una variable para poder darle la lectura del archivo
xls = pd.read_excel('NombreArchivo.xlsx','Hoja1',usecols=['UO','Estatus_Equipo','Estatus_Eq_Disponible','No_Ptas'])

# Declaramos otra variable para poder hacer el filtro
filtro = xls[ (xls.UO.isin(['TLALNEPANTLA', 'TLALNEPANTLA 2'])) & (xls.Estatus_Equipo == 'DISPONIBLE') ] 

#Muestra la información que contiene la variable filtro
print ( filtro )

#Crea el archivo con extensión .XLSX sin los indices (automáticamente se guarda en mi equipo)
filtro.to_excel('Filtrado.xlsx', index=False)

# Declaramos una variable para poder leer el archivo creado (guardado en equipo)
fx = open('Filtrado.xlsx','rb')

# Subimos el archivo
conn.upload('Filtrado.xlsx',fx,'S3bucket')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En las lambdas es posible guardar archivos en local, pero tienen que ser bajo la ruta "/tmp/". Tiene un límite de almacenamiento temporal en disco de 500MB (ampliable).

REF: https://aws.amazon.com/es/lambda/faqs/ apartado P: ¿Qué sucede si necesito espacio de desecho en disco para la función de AWS Lambda?

Con varias pruebas que he realizado, he podido observar que a veces se comparte dicho almacenamiento.

Te adjunto un código de ejemplo por si quieres hacer una prueba

```
# os necesario para poder eliminar los archivos de disco y boto3 para acceder a recursos de amazon, en este caso el s3
import os
import boto3

os.system("rm -rf /tmp/*")

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("bucketPrueba")

bucket.download_file("rutaEnS3ArchivoADescargarPorEjemploUnPDF", "/tmp/nombreFicheroTemporalEnDisco.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu diagnóstico es correcto y lo que necesitas es un objeto *file-like* en memoria y no un archivo en disco, puedes hacer uso de [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
import io

fx = io.BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fx, engine='xlsxwriter')
filtro.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
fx.seek(0)

conn.upload('Filtrado.xlsx', fx, 'S3bucket')
```

Este método funciona perfectamente con Pandas >= 0.17 y en principio, mirando el código fuente por encima, no debe haber ningún problema con `tinys3.Connection.upload`, aunque no puedo comprobar esto último.

Comment: Eres un crack, se arreglo el error, y también el error era por que configure mal el tiempo de espera de lambda, muchas gracias